# chrome extension "chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener" not fired

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, focus

I think it's a bug, just wanted to make sure that I'm doing it right
this is in my bg script

**background.js**

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(windowId) {
    console.log("Focus changed.");
    console.log(windowId);  
});
```

event is fired when Chrome is in window mode and minimize button is clicked(-1) or when switching focus between Chrome windows (including background page inspect window), but if I toggle Chrome window visibility from win7 task-bar clicking on "badge" (restore or minimize it), nothing happens.
Also if some other window/app takes focus, event is not fired (when Chrome window goes back, or to front)

Is there a solution for this or... it is a bug?

Comment: This sounds like a bug, please file on crbug.com/new

Comment: @kalman  I did ... [link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=387377&thanks=387377&ts=1403370788)