# Chrome extension window.onFocusChanged strange behavior

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension who should get when browser is focused or not. I'm using a background script defined in my mainfest.json. Something like this:

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(window){
    if (window == chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE) {
        //Do something
    }
});
```

But the event isn't always fired on focus change.
I've followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307465/chrome-extension-chrome-windows-onfocuschanged-addlistener-not-fired) and its relative answer to the Google Issue Forum [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=387377&thanks=387377&ts=1403370788).

**From google docs**

> Fired when the currently focused window changes. Will be chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE if all chrome windows have lost focus.

**From issue answers Jan 20, 2015**

> [...]chrome does not fire onfocusChange event in every possible
>   situation, only between chrome windows or between another app if new
>   tab is currently active tab. [...]it looks like dev's not interested currently in chrome.windows API

**My question.**
Is it actually possible catch anytime the browser has focus in a chrome extension?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36009207/chrome-windows-onfocuschanged-addlistener-not-firing-on-tab-switching

Comment: Just checked thank you. So, does anyone know how to get when window is focused from a chrome extension? I'm asking if are there any ways to do that at this moment..

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example of this event not firing (including OS)?